# when internet connection is lost how do store the data in a list and resend

Tags: android, connection, wait

I am trying to post data on to the server from my android app.if connection is lost between server and client i need to store these values into a list and resend these values by continuously trying for a connection .

Answer (score 1):

You could use sqlite to store this data and then use AsyncTask doInBackground() to try to check for internet connection and to send this data back to ur server.

Comment: can i use arraylist to save data temporarily

Comment: Can. Only if ur app running in the background.